# XPages - how to configure client side validation for Dojo Filtering Select controls?

Tags: dojo, xpages

I'm trying to get client side validation working with a Dojo Filtering Select, however it just does not work :-( Here is the code for the filtering select. Can anyone say what is wrong or what is missing here?

```
<xe:djFilteringSelect id="djFilteringSelect1">
<xe:this.dojoAttributes>
<xp:dojoAttribute name="required" value="true">
</xp:dojoAttribute>
<xp:dojoAttribute name="missingMessage" value="please add a value to this field!">
</xp:dojoAttribute>
</xe:this.dojoAttributes>
<xp:selectItem itemLabel=""></xp:selectItem>
<xp:selectItem itemLabel="Acai"></xp:selectItem>
 <xp:selectItem itemLabel="Apple"></xp:selectItem>
<xp:selectItem itemLabel="Apricot"></xp:selectItem>
<xp:selectItem itemLabel="Artichoke"></xp:selectItem>
<xp:selectItem itemLabel="Asparagus"></xp:selectItem>
<xp:selectItem itemLabel="Avocado"></xp:selectItem>
</xe:djFilteringSelect>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you add an **empty** value to the list of `selectItem`s then this value is a **valid** value.

Just replace this line in your code

```
<xp:selectItem itemLabel=""></xp:selectItem>
```

with

```
<xe:this.defaultValue><![CDATA[""]]></xe:this.defaultValue>
```

then you get the missing message you expected if field is empty during submit.